# Wikipedia's line intersection formula can't handle large numbers?

Tags: c++, numbers, lines

I'm working on a little game that needed a function to calculate the point of intersection of two lines. So I got this formula off Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection) and made it into a function.

```
bool lineline(int L1X1, int L1Y1, int L1X2, int L1Y2, int L2X1, int L2Y1, int L2X2, int L2Y2, int* X, int* Y) { // Returns the point of intersection of two lines
    int D = (L1X1 - L1X2) * (L2Y1 - L2Y2) - (L1Y1 - L1Y2) * (L2X1 - L2X2); // Denominator. If zero then no intersection

    if (D == 0) { // Parallel and possibly overlapping
        return false;
    } else {
        *X = ( (L1X1 * L1Y2 - L1Y1 * L1X2) * (L2X1 - L2X2) - (L1X1 - L1X2) * (L2X1 * L2Y2 - L2Y1 * L2X2) ) / D; // Calculate x
        *Y = ( (L1X1 * L1Y2 - L1Y1 * L1X2) * (L2Y1 - L2Y2) - (L1Y1 - L1Y2) * (L2X1 * L2Y2 - L2Y1 * L2X2) ) / D; // Calculate y

        std::cout << D << " | " << *X << " | " << *Y << "\n";

        if (*X >= Bmin(L1X1, L1X2) && *X <= Bmax(L1X1, L1X2) && *Y >= Bmin(L1Y1, L1Y2) && *Y <= Bmax(L1Y1, L1Y2)) {
            // Intersection is on first line
            if (*X >= Bmin(L2X1, L2X2) && *X <= Bmax(L2X1, L2X2) && *Y >= Bmin(L2Y1, L2Y2) && *Y <= Bmax(L2Y1, L2Y2)) {
                // Intersection is on second line
                return true;
            } else {
                // Intersection is on first, but not on second line
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Intersection is not on first line.
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

It works pretty well, for example when I call it with these arguments it returns true

```
lineline(400, 0, 400, 2000, 0, 400, 2000, 400, &x, &y);
```

However, when I move the second line up 1300 units...

```
lineline(400, 0, 400, 2000, 0, 1700, 2000, 1700, &x, &y) == false;
```

It returns false. While the two lines from the second function call should intersect, right? The values it calculates with these parameters are:

```
D = -4000000
*X = 400;
*Y = -447;
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I've been stuck on this for a day now and I'm probably just missing something simple, just like last time, but I can't see it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't analyzed this in any detail, but it sounds like integer overflow.

Comment: It's not Wikipedia's formula, it's the bit width of integers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula raises the differences between the input numbers to the third degree, so if the differences have roughly three digits, you should be careful about overflowing an `int`, which has nine digits, plus the first digit can go up to 2. once you overflow an `int`, you start seeing negative numbers as a result of multiplying positive ones, so the rest of your calculations becomes incorrect.

To improve the range, use 64-bit integers (i.e. `long long`) for your intermediate results.

Comment: That sounds really logical. I changed the numbers to long long's and now it works, even with very big numbers. I've got the feeling that this algorithm isn't very efficiënt, surely now that I use these big datatypes. But it's good enough for this little project I guess. I'll have to find/make a better algorithm next time haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but can't you rescale the values? E.g. divide all with the biggest and use the float results, you will have the same sizes in simply a different ratio. Since you do not need an exact cross point this should work, only remember you won't get 0 for parallel lines, so you must use a really small value alpha to define the range 0 +/- alpha that will define the D values for parallel lines.